# perl match whole word only with array list

Tags: string, perl, match

I need to be able to match a user to a list of users, but only an exact match.
In the sample code below:
- if strUser contains "info" there is a match and that's good.
- if strUser contains "theinfo", or "infostuff" there is a match and that's not good.
I can't use \b modifiers because the variable will only contain the user name, no spaces or word boundaries.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$strUser = "theinfo";
$strUsers = "(alpha|info|omega)";
if ( $strUser =~ /$strUsers/ ) {
 print "match\n";
}
exit(0);
```

Comment: Closing due to trivialness. (OP used `"\b"` instead of `"\\b"` to create a string consisting of `\b`, a problem that's evident under `use warnings;`)

Comment: Retracted due to the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: Not using `use strict; use warnings;` is like driving your car in the dark without headlights and seatbelt on: You're not less likely to crash and die, you are just unaware of it until it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a boundaries within your regex `^` and `\z`:

```
if ( $strUser =~ /^$strUsers\z/ ) {
```

Note, since you're likely wanting to work with literal strings, I would put more effort into constructing your regex by using `quotemeta`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strUser = "theinfo";

my @users = qw(alpha info omega);

my $list_users_re = join '|', map {quotemeta} @users;

if ( $strUser =~ /^($list_users_re)\z/ ) {
    print "match\n";
}

exit(0);
```

However, an even easier solution since you're looking for exact matches, is just to use a hash:

```
my @users = qw(alpha info omega);

my %is_user = map { $_ => 1 } @users;

if ( $is_user{$strUser} ) {
    print "match\n";
}
```

Finally, always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.

Comment: Thanks ... that worked ... earlier I tried using \b in the $strUsers and I should have used it in the if statement.  Will accept answer when time is up.

Comment: @Xi Vix, `\b` works in `$strUsers` too. You probably forgot to escape the `\ `. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, ty @ikegami.  Wasn't thinking about that.  Will include that in my refining.

Comment: `^\z` look a bit incongruous to me… Obviously it’s only a style issue but pairing `\A\z` or `^$` match better for my eye.

Comment: @Ashley That's fair.  I personally would probably use `^$`, but that is dependent on whether or not the OP's data could potentially include line endings.  I'm betting it won't, but would rather give the technically correct answer than to bet.